# node js with firebase function does not return anything

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

the post method does not return anything and likewise the get method
the code is on node js using firebase
the fire base setup has been done
but when a json is passed it returns empty

```
exports.postBlog = (req, res) => {
  (async() => {
    try {
      await dbs.collection('myBlog').doc('zim').set(data);

      return res.status(200).send();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("there was an error running this file");
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  })();
};

exports.getblog = (req, res) => {
  (async() => {
    try {
      const page = dbs.collection('myblog').doc('zim');
      await page.get(data);

      return res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  })();
};
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understand what the problem is. 1) Where are you running this code? 2) When you debug this code line by line, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: am running the code on vs code, the syntax is ok, but when u post a json object it returns  empty. its node js code

Comment: when i deploy it on command promp it deploys, but when u send a .json it returns empty

Comment: `exports.postBlog  = (req, res) =>{
    (async () =>{
        try { 
            const data = {
                title: 'chief',
                body: 'chest',
                footer: 'date'
            }; 
            await dbs.collection('myBlog').doc('zim').set(data);     
                    
            return res.status(200).send();
        }catch(error){
            console.log("there was an error running this file");
            return res.status(500).send(error);            
        }
    })();
};`

Comment: when i pass in something it returns empty

Comment: It looks like you're not sending back any body in the response to `postBlog` here `res.status(200).send()`, so I'd indeed expect any code that calls this to not show a response body.

Comment: `exports.postBlog = async (req, res) => { try { ...} catch (e) {}};`

Comment: how can i fix the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not know what exectly you are using, but probably using some `node` server like `express`. Generally all `respose` documentation you may find [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res). I assume that the code is working and it does not return any errors.

So, in `postBlog` you have to return something in `send` method, depending what you want to return in response. Simplest example would be to return a text ex "Document saved in Firestore". To achieve that you can add parameter to send function:

```
return res.status(200).send("Document saved in Firestore");
```

Other thing is that we do not know what the function is actually doing, as it writes to firestore `undefined` object `data` (at least looking at posted code). You have to write some object in `set` method. Please find ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set)) and [example for node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js).

When it comes to `getblog` the undefined is probably because you are sending object `respose` which is not defined in the code. Again we do not know what do you want to achieve in the logic... Again data object has been used, however according to API [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) `get` can have a parameter, but those are options and usually are not used. You can try this:

```
exports.getblog = (req, res) => {
  (async() => {
    try {
      const page = dbs.collection('myblog').doc('zim');
      let documentSnapshot = await page.get();
      let response = documentSnapshot.data();

      return res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  })();
};
```

I strongly suggest to try this [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js) document which contains both `set` and `get` examples. The `get` method example write to console there, however you may easily adopt the code changing `cosole.log` to `res.status(200).send`.